# Stat usage in truss command?

Tags: shell-script, solaris, sftp

I want to get the access time and modification time of the file in unix solaris machine. The `stats command was not found in that solaris machine. Could you please suggest which is the alternative command to find the access time and modification time of the file? I used the following (which clearly didn't work):

```
sftp> truss -f -v 'lstat,lstat64' ls -d 140901.log
Invalid command.
```

Could you please suggest the command?

Answer (score 1):

`truss` is more than likely installed on your machine, the issue is you are calling it from `sftp`, not from the shell prompt.

From the latter, a way to get the access and modification time using Solaris standard commands would be:

```
$ truss -f -v 'lstat,lstat64' ls -d . 2>&1 | grep '[am]t ='
29879:          at = Jul 16 17:20:56 CEST 2014  [ 1405524056.485059303 ]
29879:          mt = Aug 18 23:34:35 CEST 2014  [ 1408397675.814979313 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/stat` is on my Solaris 11 system. It gets installed as part of the `gnu-coreutils` package.

Also, `truss` is not an `sftp` subcommand. You would want to run an `ssh` session rather than `sftp` to run `truss`.

Answer (score 0):

The `stat` command is not defined by POSIX and not available on some *nix systems. There actually are no CLI utilities defined by POSIX that will return atime. Using `perl` is one method that will work on most *nix machines. Here is a one-liner you can use in a shell script:

```
perl -sle '@s = stat($filename); print "atime: $s[8]\nmtime:$s[9]"' -- -filename=foo
```

Comment: `pax` is specified to return `atime`. `pax` is specified to do a lot of things that I can't figure out how to convince the two hard-to-find `pax`es I've managed to install to do. [The text's example](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html): `-o listopt='(name)s\n%(atime)T\n%T'`